# Having trouble adding date filter to SQL Server 2014 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, where-clause

I am using SQL Server 2014 and have a couple columns that are in date format to which I am having trouble applying a filter. I want to select records with and `orderdate > '20141231'`. When I try to add this to via the criteria pane, it tells me I must use a CONVERT function, but I don't understand why because these are already in date format and I am using standard date formatting in the filter.

I have tried manually entering the following into the query:

```
WHERE CAST(OrderDate as date) > '20141231'
```

and also

```
WHERE CAST(OrderDate as date) > 20141231
```

but I am getting an incorrect syntax near '20141231' message when ' is in place and an unable to parse message when the ' is excluded.

Any thoughts on how to overcome this? I feel like it's a simple thing, not sure where my problem is.

Thanks!

Comment: Show bigger part of query and tell where you are executing it (SSMS/your app).

Answer (score 0):

While converting string to datetime, you need to provide style as a 3rd parameter to Convert function, the where clause will look like below for the date format you are trying -

```
WHERE OrderDate > Convert(datetime, '20141231', 112)
```

other styles can be found at - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx